# BeautifulSoup: Scrape list of embedded href links

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm working on scraping information about some of the most recent trending videos here https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending. I loaded the page into BeautifulSoup but get an error when trying to run through the list of div's I need to parse.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

#narrow in to divs with relevant meta-data
videos = soup.find_all('div',class_='yt-lockup-content')
videos[50].div.a['href'] #checking one specific DIV
>>u'user/nameofchannel' #works
```

Up to this point I have returned information I need, but when I try to run through all divs (70+ on this page as of writing), I get a error related to the data type this method returns.

```
for v in videos:
     videos[v].div.a['href']
>> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Tag
```

How can I run through the list of div's returned in 'videos' and print out a list of values that match 'video[n].div.a['href'] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for v in range(len(videos)):
     videos[v].div.a['href']
```

what you need is the index of `videos` list , not the tag in it.

**Better:**

```
for index, value in enumerate(videos):
    videos[index].div.a['href']
```

**Much Better:**

```
[v.div.a['href'] for v in videos]
```

use **list comprehension** is recommended for this kind of task

Comment: Thanks! list comprehension format worked but first one did not. Error: "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"